# Static website and Angular 2 application on same domain

Tags: angular, nginx-location

I have two applications.

> 1. static (html, css)
> 2. angular2

Domain name: **xyz.com**

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

web server: nginx/1.10.3

### Purpose:

opening **xyz.com** should serve content from directory named **static**

and **xyz.com/app** should serve content from a directory named **angular2**

### angular2 AOT build application file structure

[image]

### SERVER CONFIGURATION

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name xyz.com;

    location / {

        alias /var/www/html/static/;
        # First attempt to serve request ais file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.i
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string /index.html =404;
    }

    location /app {
        alias /var/www/html/angular2/;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8086;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht { 
        deny all;
    }
  }
```

### WEBPACK CONFIGURATION

```
output: {

  /**
   * The output directory as absolute path (required).
   *
   * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-path
   */
  path: helpers.root('dist'),

  publicPath: '/app/',
  /**
   * Specifies the name of each output file on disk.
   * IMPORTANT: You must not specify an absolute path here!
   *
   * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-filename
   */
  filename: '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js',

  /**
   * The filename of the SourceMaps for the JavaScript files.
   * They are inside the output.path directory.
   *
   * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-sourcemapfilename
   */
  sourceMapFilename: '[file].map',

  /**
   * The filename of non-entry chunks as relative path
   * inside the output.path directory.
   *
   * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-chunkfilename
   */
  chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].chunk.js'

},
```

I have added **publicPath to be /app/** so that each of the files included in index.html should be prefixed with app/ (Refer index.html snippet below)

### angluar2 application index.html preview

[image]

Keeping `<base href="/app">` will prefix each route with /app so that nginx location block can serve content from angular2 application.

### Results:

When I open **xyz.com**, content from my static website gets served and 
when I open **xyz.com/app/SOME_URL_HERE**, content from my angular2 application gets served. Till now it looked okay to me!

### PROBLEM:

I am referring an image in my angular2 app from one of my html template and it has a relative path

```
<img src="../../assets/image.jpeg" />
```

my current setup is not able to serve it. I don't want to refer it having absolute path

```
<img src="app/assests/image.png" />
```

because first it will not work in my development setup and second it would make code readability harder.

Is my whole setup is wrong ?

OR

Is there any way to make nginx serve content of angular2 app relative to index.html with my current setup in place.

### References:

I am using angular-starter as application base

https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/

### EDITED

Initially, I put my angular 2 application on subdomain app.xyz.com but I had to change my decision when I got to know that to secure a domain and subdomain, I need to buy a **wildcard ssl** and it too costly for me to buy.

Answer (score 1):

I find that hosting an angular app on a path will lead to all kind of problems.

**Solution 1**

**If you can, avoid it.**

I would suggest having your app have it's own subdomain.
app.xyz.com

That way when your app grows and your site grows, it will be easier to maintain them separatly.

**Solution 2**

If your static site only is a single page site you could serve /static/index.html on /

```
location = / {
  root /var/www/html/static/;
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location / {
  root /var/www/html/angular2/;
  try_files $uri index.html
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Leon for your reply. yeah, I kept angular2 application on a subdomain app.xyz.com but I had to change my decision when I get to know that I have to buy a **wildcard SSL** to secure my domain and subdomain. It was too costly for me to buy. That is why I decided to keep it on single domain until I get some funds. :) 
Thanks for pointing it though, I would update my question.

Comment: you forgot to mention / in second location block. 
I made the changes suggested by you. But now when I make a request to my domain xyz.com, second location block is being served.

location = /
exact location match isn't working somehow. I'll test it further and will let you know if works for me.

Comment: the static website's index.html has reference to other js and css files in the directory. Those files cannot get loaded with suggested approach!

Comment: you can use letsencrypt.org for free ssl certificates. as you mentioned, you will need to also have a location block for your static resources, which means that your static site and angular app are even more intertwined. That's why the separate subdomain is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

It's always better if you can avoid deploying two applications on a single domain. Though, I couldn't avoid it due to some reasons, here is how I managed to deploy the two applications on a single domain.

I kept base as

```
<base href="">
```

instead of

```
<base href="/app">
```

so that all application assets should load relatively.

and below is the nginx configuration

```
  server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name xyz.com;

    location / {

        alias /var/www/html/static/;
        # First attempt to serve request ais file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.i
        index index.html;
    }

    location /app {
        alias /var/www/html/angular2/;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8086;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht { 
        deny all;
    }
  }
```

You might improve it by keeping a global **root** element so that if you add more location blocks, a root always be there.

I kept the HashLocation strategy for angular2 app. whenever I need to switch a user from static website to angular app. I have appended /app to the URL.